How to keep duplicated occurence records in ENMevaluate()
I am working with environmental variables in raster format and presence records in a data frame. When the environmental data is stored in grid cells, as it is when it's a raster, it considers presence records that fall within the same grid cell to be duplicates even if they have different coordinates.
I want to run ENMevaluate() but without discarding "duplicate" records.
Currently when I try to run ENMevaluate() it prints this statement in the console:
Removed 297 occurrence localities that shared the same grid cell.

Here is my code:
os <- list(other.args = list(removeduplicates = FALSE))

enmeval_results  <- ENMevaluate(pres, # presence records
                                env, # environmental layers
                                bg = bgp, # background points 
                                tune.args = list( # tuning arguments
                                  fc = c("L","LQ","H", "LQH", "LQHP", "LQHPT"), 
                                  rm = 1:5), # regularisation multiplier
                                partitions = partition,
                                algorithm = "maxent.jar", 
                                other.settings = OS)


can you try: os <- list(removeduplicates = FALSE) and
'other.settings' = os instead of 'other.settings = OS' ?
